# Emacs and latexmk setup for --shell-escape

Tags: emacs, auctex, latexmk, shell-escape

If I want `--shell-escape`, do I just need to add it to my `.latexmkrc` file as

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S
          -file-line-error -synctex=1';
```

or should it be added in my `.emacs` file (where would it go here if this is the case?)

```
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
                 (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -file-line-error  
                                   -synctex=1' -pdf %O %S" 'TeX-master-file)
                 master-file))
    (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
        (TeX-next-error t)
      (progn
        (demolish-tex-help)
        (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done."))))
```

or does it need to be in both the `.emacs` and `.latexmkrc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `latexmk` with this function, the parameter `-pdflatex='pdflatex -file-line-error -synctex=1'` will override the settings you put in your `.latexmkrc`.

You can either keep it in your `.latexmkrc` this way, and then run simply `latexmk -pdf <yourfile>`, or not worry about the `.latexmkrc` and put all compilation parameters in the `.emacs`.

The first option:

```
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
                 (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdf %O %S" 'TeX-master-file)
                 master-file))
    (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
        (TeX-next-error t)
      (progn
        (demolish-tex-help)
        (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done."))))
```

and the second:

```
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
                 (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -file-line-error  
                                   --shell-escape -synctex=1' -pdf %O %S" 'TeX-master-file)
                 master-file))
    (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
        (TeX-next-error t)
      (progn
        (demolish-tex-help)
        (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done."))))
```

In both cases, the only part you need to change is the call to `latexmk`.

Comment: So I can just delete my `.latexmkrc` file?  Can I add `interaction=nonstopmode` to option two?

Comment: You can either delete it or keep it, it won't matter. You can use it to specify more settings, or to maintain coherent settings if you don't always use it with `emacs`. For the second question, yes, the `-pdflatex` parameter is exactly equivalent to setting the `pdflatex` variable in the `.latexmkrc`.

Comment: What should the order be? This: `"latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -file-line-error
                                   --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode         
                                   -synctex=1' -pdf %O %S"` or should file line, nonstop, and/or shell escape be in a different order?

Comment: It shouldn't matter.