# Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations

Tags: biblatex, biber, editors, big-list, ide

Running the minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{example,
  author  = {Other, Anthony Norman},
  title   = {Some things I did},
  year    = {2014},
  journal = {J.~Irrep. Res.},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1-10}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Hello\cite{example}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get the warning `There were undefined references`.

I have read [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number) and know that I need to run:

1. LaTeX
2. Biber
3. LaTeX

However, my editor is only set up to run BibTeX. How do I go about setting up my editor/IDE to be able to run Biber, and how do I run the LaTeX/Biber/LaTeX cycle?

### Answers (sorted alphabetically by editor name)

- [Emacs with AUCTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154753)
- [(vanilla) Emacs (*i.e.*, without AUCTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372988)
- [GNOME LaTeX/LaTeXila](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446200/)
- [Inlage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154808)
- [Kile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154763)
- [Sublime Text with LaTeXTools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220501)
- [Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788)
- [Texlipse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635991/70136)
- [TeXniccenter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154794)
- [TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154778)
- [TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754)
- [TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154767)
- [WinEdt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154755)
- [Overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439854)
- [VSCode using LaTeX Workshop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502183)

### Answer guidelines

- Each answer should be for one editor. If the editor is cross-platform, if possible give a single answer with notes covering the minor platform variations.
- Please edit the question to include new answers in the 'link list'
- Each answer should be 'stand alone', *i.e.* don't say 'It's almost the same as editor Y but ...' *for the editor part*
- Instructions for 'build tools' such as `arara` or `latexmk` are welcome but should explain how to set up the *editor in question* as not all editors allow simple addition of arbitrary tools

Comment: For background to this question, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4192/a-single-question-for-configuring-editors-to-do-latex-biber-compilation

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex

Comment: Would "[my build script](https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any) runs biber when necessary, out of the box" be a valid answer?

Comment: @Raphael I've tried to tighten up the guidelines to cover this. Broadly, I'd expect each answer to be about an editor, with details for using build tools fine for inclusion but hopefully focussed on the editor side. Generic 'how to use build tool X' instructions can then be linked but not included directly here.

Comment: @JosephWright: I see. Maybe we can have *one* answer for people that use plain editors that don't support any build process integration? (I'm sure I'm not the only one.) That would, basically, be a list of known editor-independent build tools that support `biblatex` with explanations how.

Comment: @Raphael But those editors have exactly the same issue with BibTeX (you _have_ to run it by hand), and presumably users of these editors are entirely happy with that.

Comment: @JosephWright Not true; a build tool may run automatically, figure out which binaries are needed, etc. (know mine does). Or am I missing the point of this question? I understand it as "Given my LaTeX process, how do I switch to `biber`?". We've got people covered who a) do everything by hand or b) use their editor's features. All I'm saying is that there is a group that c) uses another build tool that might need adaption.

Comment: I'm adding a link to this from the biber documentation from version 1.9 and removing the meagre comments about this I currently have in there.

Answer (score 64):

### TeXstudio

In the current release (2.12 branch), TeXstudio's build process ('Build & View') by default runs pdfLaTeX but not a bibliography tool, which you need to do separately. There is also a need to change the settings to run Biber rather than BibTeX for creating a bibliography.

The **configuration step** sets Biber as default bibliography tool.

In the TeXstudio preferences ('Preferences ...' on the Mac or ['Options -> Configure TeXstudio' on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102803)), choose the *Build* tab and alter the 'Default Bibliography Tool' to 'Biber'. Save and close the preferences.

[image: Default Bibliography Tool: Biber]

The **compile step** is to ensure that the sequence

1. LaTeX
2. Biber
3. LaTeX

is run. Manually this can be done as follows.

1. Run 'Build & View' from the 'Tools' menu (or press the two green arrows icon), which will create a PDF but with the bibliography not completed
2. Run 'Bibliography' from the 'Tools' menu.

   [image: Tools > Bibliography]
3. Run 'Build & View' again: the bibliography will appear in the PDF.

It is possible to set up TeXstudio in [alternative ways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140969/biblatex-isnt-writing-out-bibliography) to achieve the same effect. The key is that you have to run the compile sequence LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, which can be done 'by hand' (as I have) or can be automated in various ways. Note that the same general idea applies whatever editor is used: this is a feature of LaTeX and not of the editor.

#### Changing the bibliography tool only for a specific document

If you only want Biber for a single document, it is possible to specify this in the `.tex` file itself, using a so-called "magic comment". Simply add the following line at the top of your main .tex file:

```latex
% !TeX TXS-program:bibliography = txs:///biber
```

Or, if you want compatibility with the TeXShop and TeXWorks editors, use this instead:

```latex
% !BIB TS-program = biber
```

More details: [TeXstudio user manual: 4.10 Advanced header usage](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION_TEXCOM), 
[When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78101/when-and-why-should-i-use-tex-ts-program-and-tex-encoding)

Comment: More or less what I put in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153647/biblatex-biber-and-latex-citations-undefined

Comment: Also note that we need to install `biber`.

Comment: Important note: in addition to the above, to run `biber` with TeXstudio on **windows 10**, you should run TeXstudio "as administrator" from windows. Otherwise, `biber` won't be executed from the editor no matter what options you changed.

Comment: @hesham In general it should not be necessary to run TeXstudio as administrator just to be be able to run Biber. It should be possible to execute Biber from within TeXstudio with only user permissions. I consider it quite dangerous to open an editor with admin permissions. If your Biber or TeXstudio requires admin permissions, then there is probably something wrong with your installation.

Comment: When I switch to Biblatex and Biber, TeXstudio does not give me any autocomplete for my citations anymore. Instead the editor just says "Citation missing", even though the PDF builds fine and the references are ok.
With normal Bibtex, TeXstudio always autocompleted/suggested my citations. Is there anythign I can do about this?

Comment: I wish I could give you an extra upvote for that magic command. Definitely owe you a beer.

Answer (score 52):

## Texmaker

---

**Through `Quick Build` for *`ALL`* documents**

Click on `Options` → `Configure Texmaker`:

[image]

The following window opens. In `Commands` tab replace `bibtex %` by

```
biber %
```

Make sure that you *only* have `%` after the path to Biber and not `%.aux`.

If for some reason, `biber %` does not work, you may want to try browsing to the `biber.exe` using the `folder` icon on the side (red arrow):

[image]

Though generally `biber %` should just work (and is preferable over `biber.exe %`).

This will make Biber the default for all documents.

Now choose the `Quick Build` tab in which further choose the second option as in the following figure:

[image]

Now your quick buid button should run `pdflatex` → `biber` → `pdflatex` → `view pdf`. In all steps above, don't forget to press  <kbd>OK</kbd>  in all windows before exiting.

---

**Making only `biber` as user command**

Go to `User` → `User Commands` → `Edit User Commands` as in the following figure:

[image]

In the window that opens, type in the content as shown (ignore `arara` thing ;-)..):

[image]

Now your build list should have `biber`:

[image]

Now, you can choose to run (only) `biber` as standalone when you wish.

Comment: `Texmaker-biber-biblatex` usage Documentation in French for http://xm1math.net/doculatex/biblatex.html

Comment: Similar procedure on Linux just replace `bibtex %.aux` to `biber %` in Bib(la)tex command box without full path to binaries. I suppose this would work with MiKTeX and TeXLive distro if miktex bin and texlive bin path are added to system path.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/biblatex-biber-texmaker-miktex

Comment: if i choose to run (only) biber as standalone when you wish. What is the sequence of buttons I have to push? Is it command 2 + quick build or quick build + command 2? Thanks. @Harish Kumar

Comment: Are there any updates to this question using TeXmaker? I did this but still don't have bibliography in my document.

Answer (score 29):

## Emacs with AUCTeX

(adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129237/31416))

---

### AUCTeX Version 11.88

Version 11.88 has (currently) probably the best support for `biber` and `biblatex` among *TeX editors: AUCTeX is able to look at `biblatex` load options to automatically choose the right bibliography processor on a per-document basis, you need only to enable file parsing by setting [`TeX-parse-self`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dparse_002dself) to `t`.    You can do that by adding the following code to your `.emacs`

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

or customizing that variable with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `TeX-parse-self` <kbd>RET</kbd>.  Most AUCTeX users enable parsing, probably you've already done that, check it before adding the above line to your `.emacs`.  To see the value of the variable issue <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `TeX-parse-self` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

As in the previous version, <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> ([`TeX-command-master`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dcommand_002dmaster)) prompts for `biber`/`bibtex` when the `.bbl` file is newer than the `.tex` file (but now it prompts for the appropriate bibliography processor, and not always `biber` or `bibtex`).  In addition, if you use the toolbar, in this version the bibliography button will automatically switch between `Run BibTeX` and `Run Biber`.

In this version, the variable [`LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-LaTeX_002dbiblatex_002duse_002dBiber) is local (and no more customizable) for cases in which AUCTeX fails to automatically detect the correct processor.

### AUCTeX Version 11.87

Version 11.87 is the first release of AUCTeX supporting `biber` by default and you don't need to add that processor to the command list.  You can always run `biber` by hand with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> `Biber` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

#### Set `biber` as default bibliography processor

AUCTeX uses `bibtex` as default bibliography processor.  In order to set `biber` as default bibliography processor (*for all documents* and not on a per-document basis) you have to activate parsing of LaTeX documents by setting the variable `TeX-parse-self` to `t` (see above).  Then, in source files with an explicit

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

line, <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> prompts for `biber` or `bibtex` processor when needed (ie, if the `.bbl` file is newer than the `.tex` file), depending on the value of the customizable option `LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber`, which defaults to `t`.  But until version 11.87, AUCTeX isn't able to *automatically* choose the bibliography processor, which is set in a LaTeX document with the `backend` load option of the `biblatex` package.  Unfortunately, the bibliography button on the toolbar is always bound to `Run BibTeX`, even if `LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber` is set to `t`.

---

### Run `latexmk`

You can also run `latexmk` from AUCTeX.  It isn't supported by default, but you can manually add it to `TeX-command-list`.  Here are some Q&As on TeX Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow about how to setup `latexmk` in AUCTeX:

- [How to call latexmk in emacs, and jump to next-error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2199678/2442087)
- [Compile using latexmk in emacs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10561/31416)
- [Emacs and latexmk setup for --shell-escape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124793/31416)
- [How to make `latexmk` run the appropriate amount of times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115247/31416)
- [How do I bind latexmk to one key in Emacs and have it show errors if there are any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7587287/2442087) and the follow up [Emacs latexmk function throws me into an empty buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7885853/2442087)

Comment: I know some people use Emacs without AUCTeX, but I still can't understand what the killer feature is that vanilla Emacs provides.  (At least with respect to LaTeX.)

Comment: @jon Well Emacs pops up in more than one answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides, so presumably some people use Emacs without AUCTeX. I guess the argument is that it's a good text editor in general, and without an add-in you get the same behaviour irrespective of the file you're editing. In any case, that doesn't affect the aim here :-)

Comment: @JosephWright -- Indeed.  I pratically live inside Emacs and I'm not a computer person!  I meant it more as a sort of (light-hearted) provocative, tongue-in-cheek, comment.  Although I have often wondered what AUCTeX did badly or what plain Emacs did particularly well, or if it was simply a matter or what one is used to, rather like the divide between vi(m) and Emacs.

Comment: @jon I suspect most `tex-mode` users aren't *TeX hard-core users, so they don't take advantage of the advanced features of AUCTeX: `tex-mode` is a lightweight package (admittedly, you can say the same for AUCTeX), provides a decent syntax highlighting and allows to build a document, this is sufficient for them.  But, speaking for myself, I can't live without the AUCTeX amazing editing facilities.

Comment: @giordano -- I suppose that is true.  I never gave it much of a chance myself, because (somehow, I forget now) I learned early on that AUCTeX (and RefTeX) was the way to go....

Comment: In my previous comment, "admittedly, you can say the same for AUCTeX" should read "admittedly, you **can't** say the same for AUCTeX" `:-)`.

Comment: I just added a ['vanilla' Emacs answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372988/32888) for anyone interested and/or stuck using vanilla Emacs. `:-p`

Comment: I was running the Biber command through AUCTeX and nothing was working until I performed `apt-get install biber` for my Ubuntu system.  Is this a step that other people might need to perform, and if so should it be mentioned here?

Comment: @dpritch Well, it should be mentioned in the question post, rather in this answer.  Anyway, I guess it should be safe to assume that one installs biber before trying to use it ;-)

Answer (score 26):

## TeXShop

### Changing for all documents

If you want to make `biber` the default bibliography tool, you can simply change it in the TeXShop Engine preference panel.

Now the command is accessed in the same way that you would access `bibtex`: from the Typeset Menu choose Bibtex (Command-Shift-B).

[image: preference pane]

### Changing on a per-document basis

Since most of us who are switching to `biber` still have documents which use `bibtex` it is often more useful to specify the bibliography engine directly in the document in the same way that other engines can be specified.  See the following question for a full description of these possibilities.

- [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/2693)

To specify the bibliography program as `biber` or `bibtex` per document use either of the following lines at the beginning of your document.  This will override what the default is set to on a per document basis. (To use `bibtex` on a document, replace `biber` with `bibtex`.)

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
```

Alternatively, if you prefer an all-in-one command solution, you can use one of the various `latexmk` Engines that TeXShop provides.  In this case you would instead one of the following lines to your document, according to the TeX engine you are using:

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatexmk
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk
% !TeX TS-program = lualatexmk
```

See the following question for how to do this:

- [all-in-one-engine for TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41271/all-in-one-engine-for-texshop)

Comment: Is it necessary to change paths with the advent of El Capitan here? I.e. something along the lines of `/ust/texbin` -> `/Library/TeX/texbin`?

Comment: If you use the (pdf)latexmk engine it will automatically choose between biber and bibtex. For more information about those engines see the  Help->TeXShop Tips and Tricks document. Note: you may have to activate some of the engines (e.g., pdflatexmk is pre-activated but the latexmk engine may not be pre-activated).

Answer (score 25):

### TeXworks

The list of binaries known by TeXworks depends on where you get the program from: direct from the [TeXworks site](http://tug.org/texworks/) or as part of TeX Live or MiKTeX. However, at present Biber is not included in the standard set in any case. The steps needed to add Biber as an option are as follows:

1. In the TeXworks preferences ('Preferences ...' on the Mac or 'Edit -> Preferences' on Windows/Linux, choose the 'Typesetting' tab.
   [image: Go to "Edit > Preferences" and choose the "Typesetting" tab]
2. Use the '+' icon to add a new entry to to the 'Processing tool' list
   [image: The "+" button is in the lower right corner of the "Processing tool" list]
3. Fill in the resulting box as follows:

   - Name: Biber
   - Program: biber
   - Arguments: `$basename` (use the 'plus' icon to add in a line for an argument)
   - 'View PDF after running': untick

   then OK this box and the preferences.

   [image: The tool configuration window should have Biber as Name, biber as program, $basename in the Arguments window (where lines can be added with the "+" button), "View PDF after running" should be unchecked]

   *If* 'biber' cannot be found if the *Program* entry reads only `biber`, you can browse for the full path `filespec/biber.ext` to the Biber executable. *But this should usually not be necessary.*
4. To compile the document using Biber, first run pdfLaTeX (or XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX) as normal, then choose 'Biber' from the dropdown and run it, before going back to pdfLaTeX and running it.

---

Build tools such as [`latexmk`](http://users.phys.psu.edu/%7Ecollins/software/latexmk-jcc/) or [`arara`](https://github.com/cereda/arara) can be set up in a similar way, probably leaving 'View PDF after running' ticked.

Answer (score 23):

### WinEdt

If you want to make Biber the default tool for compiling bibliographies, you have to go to "Options" -> "Execution Modes", "Console Application" panel, and change the value of the "Executable" field for the BibTeX accessory from `bibtex.exe` to `biber.exe`:

[image]

In this way, each time you launch the command BibTeX, WinEdt will execute Biber.

Even when you launch commands like [PDFTeXify](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119105/27635) (and using MiKTeX's `texify.exe` as engine), WinEdt will be able to compile the bibliography with Biber.

---

**LaTeXify add-on**

For WinEdt versions 7 and above, there is a configuration component called "LaTeXify" available on http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/LaTeXify.html. It is provided with an install and an uninstall macro.

After installing it, you will have the chance to run either BibTeX or Biber, through toolbar buttons, menu items or keyboard shortcuts.

[image]

Apart from Biber, the add-on LaTeXify also adds commands for automated compilations, like PDFTeXify.

Here is a list

- XeTeXify (runs BibTeX and PDFTeXify with XeLaTeX engine)
- LuaTeXify (runs BibTeX and PDFTeXify with LuaLaTeX engine)
- TeXify2PDF (runs BibTeX and TeXify+dvips+ps2pdf with LaTeX engine, v10 only)
- LaTeXify (runs Biber and TeXify with LaTeX engine)
- PDFLaTeXify (runs Biber and PDFTeXify with PDFLaTeX engine)
- XeLaTeXify (runs Biber and PDFTeXify with XeLaTeX engine)
- LuaLaTeXify (runs Biber and PDFTeXify with LuaLaTeX engine)
- LaTeXify2PDF (runs Biber and TeXify+dvips+ps2pdf with LaTeX engine, v10 only)

Answer (score 17):

## TeXnicCenter

---

**Through `LaTeX → PDF` menu For *`ALL`* documents**

Go to `Build` → `Define Output Profiles`:

[image]

In the window that opens, choose any profile (say `LaTeX` → `PDF`) and make the changes for `bibtex` field as in the following figure (again you can browse the `biber.exe`, see red arrow on the right).

[image]

Press `OK` and exit. Now in the main window choose `LaTeX` → `PDF` from the build drop down tool button:

[image]

If you compile, `biber` is used now for all documents.

---

**Making only `biber` as a standalone profile**

Go to `Build` → `Define Output Profiles` as explained before. Click on <kbd>Add</kbd> (1). In the window that opens type `Biber` (2), click `OK` to get `Biber` entry in the profile (3):

[image]

Now choose the profile `Biber`. In the window,

1. *Un-check* `Run (La)TeX in this profile`.
2. *Un-check* `Do not use BibTeX in this profile`.
3. *Check* `Do not use MakeIndex in this profile`.
4. Fill in the content for Path to BibTeX. You can also browse to `biber.exe` (see the red arrow to right).
5. Fill in the Command line arguments to pass to as shown.

All 5 above in the following figure:

[image]

Now your build drop down tool bar has `Biber`. Choose and compile:

[image]

In all steps above, don't forget to press OK in all windows before exiting.

Comment: Hello @user11232! I used `biblatex/Biber` (with `TeXnicCenter` and portable `MiKTeX`, all up to date) for the very first time and discovered following: If I use a single `.tex` file without the `TeXnicCenter` project file `.tcp`, than the `BibTeX` button is gray [out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVr1d.png) (it's german). First when I created a `TeXnicCenter` project, I could use the `BibTeX` button. Maybe it's only my machine. Maybe it's a normal case, I don't know. I used following `TeXnicCenter` [profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYT9r.png) (it's german).

Answer (score 16):

## Kile (2.1.3)

This answer is adapted from [the TeXStudio answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754/73).

Kile's build process may or may not run a bibliography tool in addition to running LaTeX or PDFLaTeX. It will depend on precisely which Build option is run. In some cases, then, you may need to run the bibliography tool separately.

### Using BibTeX

1. To compile a document with BibTeX:

   - Choose 'Build -> Compile -> your preferred tool e.g. LaTeX or PDFLaTeX'
   - Choose 'Build -> Compile -> BibTeX'
   - Choose 'Build -> Compile -> your preferred tool'
   - Choose 'Build -> Compile -> your preferred tool'

It is possible to set up Kile in alternative ways to achieve the same effect. The key is that you have to ensure that there is a sequence

```
LaTeX
BibTeX
LaTeX
LaTeX
```

which can be done 'by hand' (as I have) or can be automated in various ways. Note that the same general idea applies whatever editor is used: this is a feature of LaTeX and not of the editor.

### Using Biber

By  default, Kile will never run Biber rather than BibTeX. Enabling Biber requires you to change the settings. The steps to do this are as follows:

1. In Kile, open the preferences dialogue using 'Settings -> Configure Kile...'. Choose 'Tools -> Build' from the menu on the left.
2. Under 'Select a Tool' there is a button 'New...'. Click this to create an option for Biber. When asked for a 'short descriptive name', type `Biber` and click 'Next'. From the dropdown menu, set the class of the new tool as 'BibTeX' and then click 'Finish'. This means the new tool will inherit BibTeX's settings as a basis.
3. To configure the new tool, choose 'Biber' from the list under 'Select a tool'. On the right, you now have a detailed set of options. Leave the dropdown menu at the top on 'Default'. Then configure the options for the tabs underneath.
4. 'General' tab:

   - 'Command': type `biber` (deleting anything already there)
   - 'Options': make sure this says `'%S'` (including the quotation marks)

   At this point, it should look like this:

   [image: Kile with new tool, Biber, and the options in the 'General' tab configured]
5. 'Advanced' tab:

   - 'Type': select 'Run outside of Kile'
   - 'Class': select 'Compile'
   - 'Source extension': type `bcf`
   - 'Target extension': type `bbl`
   - 'Target file': leave blank
   - 'Relative directory': leave blank
   - 'State': select 'Editor'

   So the contents of the 'Advanced' tab should be:

   [image: Configuring options in the 'Advanced' tab for Biber]
6. 'Menu' tab:

   - 'Add tool to Build menu': select 'Compile' (unless you have different ideas)
   - 'Icon': select/set as you wish
7. Before applying your changes, check any build tools you use regularly from the list under 'Select a tool'. If any of these are set to run BibTeX, rather than Biber, change the commands appropriately.
8. Click 'OK' at the bottom right of the dialogue.
9. To compile a document with Biber rather than BibTeX:

   - Choose 'Build -> Compile -> your preferred tool e.g. LaTeX or PDFLaTeX'
   - Choose 'Build -> Compile -> Biber'
   - Choose 'Build -> Compile -> your preferred tool'
   - Choose 'Build -> Compile -> your preferred tool' (if a second run is required)

It is possible to set up Kile in alternative ways to achieve the same effect. The key is that you have to ensure that there is a sequence

```
LaTeX
Biber
LaTeX
```

which can be done 'by hand' (as I have) or can be automated in various ways. Note that the same general idea applies whatever editor is used: this is a feature of LaTeX and not of the editor.

Comment: Also of note: if a document includes the string `\bibliography`, Kile 2.1.3 is hard-coded to automatically run Bibtex after LaTeX or PDFLaTeX. To disable this, you have to click on LaTeX or PDFLaTeX or so on (whichever you are using) in the "Select a tool" list and uncheck the "Automatically run additional tools" checkbox; this will also disable automatic running of MakeIndex and Asymptote. However, future versions of Kile will detect the biblatex backend in use and run the appropriate tool, Biber or Bibtex.

Answer (score 16):

## VSCode using the LaTeX Workshop extension

First, ensure that you already have:

- installed the [LaTeX Workshop extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop),
- configured it properly to [build and view a minimal LaTeX PDF file](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Install#usage),
- [a minimal document for biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13513/145453) ready.

Then,

1. Open the Settings JSON file as instructed below:

1.1. Click on the **Manage** gear icon, and then select **Settings** on the menu that appears.

[image: Click on the Manage gear icon]

1.2. Click on the curly braces pair on the top right of the window.

[image: Select Settings]

2. Add or append (if already exists) the biber tool entry, and the compile recipe to the LaTeX Workshop entry in the opened JSON file:

- The biber tool entry:

```json
{
    "name": "biber",
    "command": "biber",
    "args": [
        "%DOCFILE%"
    ]
}
```

- The compile recipe for biber using xelatex:

```json
{
  "name": "xelatex -> biber -> xelatex*2",
  "tools": [
      "xelatex",
      "biber",
      "xelatex",
      "xelatex"
  ]
}
```

The whole LaTeX Workshop settings section should look like the following (your section could include other entries):

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
      {
          "name": "xelatex -> biber -> xelatex*2",
          "tools": [
              "xelatex",
              "biber",
              "xelatex",
              "xelatex"
          ]
      },      
  ],
  "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [{
      {
          "name": "pdflatex",
          "command": "pdflatex",
          "args": [
              "-synctex=1",
              "-interaction=nonstopmode",
              "-file-line-error",
              "%DOC%"
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "bibtex",
          "command": "bibtex",
          "args": [
              "%DOCFILE%"
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "biber",
          "command": "biber",
          "args": [
              "%DOCFILE%"
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "xelatex",
          "command": "xelatex",
          "args": [
              "-synctex=1",
              "-interaction=nonstopmode",
              "-file-line-error",
              "%DOC%"
          ]
      }
  }
  ]
```

Now you can click on the recipe title on the sidebar under LaTeX Workshop to build and view the file.

---

Using a recent VSCode LaTeX Workshop extension, an upgrade to `intellisense` in September 2021 ([on GitHub here](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/commit/9dfc0f4eb46a9fdefc77505e8de8e9353b133da3)) made `bibtex` the default backend for VSCode so the following code needs to be added to your `settings.json` for the backend to be changed to `biblatex`:

```
"latex-workshop.intellisense.citation.backend": "biblatex",
```

Now the recipes from above will be able to run when using `biber` and not throw errors or undefined references [similar to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685494/273733). Further information can be found on the LaTeX-Workshop [intellisense FAQ hosted on GitHub here](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Intellisense).

Comment: I have tried to do this, but substituting 'pdflatex' in place of 'xelatex' and it doesn't work. The error message says "pdflatex not defined". What should I do?

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos Do you have the `pdflatex` element defined as above (with `name`, `command`, and `args` keys) under  `latex-workshop.latex.tools`? It's not just the recipes; the `latex-workshop.latex.tools` must contain all the _tools_ declared under the `recipes` key.

Comment: I don't know what was going on, but now it is working without any changes in the .json file

Answer (score 14):

## Overleaf

Overleaf uses `latexmk` as the build tool behind the scenes, so `bibtex` or `biber` will be executed as needed, as well as re-running `pdflatex`. So there is no further action required on the part of the user.

Comment: Not completely related to the editor configuration. Still, it is probably useful to keep a small note here: `latexmk` is a great tool. There are a few rare edge cases where it can get hung up in an "error loop". In that case it may help to delete the Overleaf cache (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache) and recompile from scratch.

Answer (score 12):

### Sublime Text 2 & 3 with LaTeXTools

For more on using Biber with LaTeXTools, see [this wiki page](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/wiki/Biber-Support). There are a few options depending on your OS and preferred configuration.

#### Using the default build engine ("traditional") with MacTeX (OSX) or TeXLive (Windows/OSX/Linux):

On these platforms, LaTeXtools' default (or "traditional") build engine uses `latexmk` by default. `latexmk`, in turn, supports `biber`+`biblatex` out of the box [as of version 4.22](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/latexmk/versions.html) (at least in principle; there have been a few bug fixes since then regarding biber). Hence it doesn't make any difference for LaTeXTools whether you use bibtex or biber because it only cares about your .bib files (whose format does not depend on your choice of bibtex/biber) and supports both `\bibliography` and `\addbibresource`. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to build should be all you need to do.

Put differently, if you experience any issues, try `$ latexmk <yourtexfile>.tex` on the command line first.

#### Using the default build engine ("traditional") with MikTeX (Windows):

With MikTeX, LaTeXtools' default builder will use `textify`. Unfortunately, `texify` doesn't seem to support `biber`. However, it is possible to install and use `latexmk` on MiKTeX. After installing `latexmk` on MiKTeX, navigate to the user settings.

[image: image showing navigating to Preferences > Package Settings > LaTeXTools > Settings - User]

Then scroll down to the `builder_settings` block and add the line `"command": "latexmk -cd -f -%E -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1"` as shown.

[image: image showing adding "command": "latexmk -cd -f -%E -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1" to builder settings]

#### Using "basic" build:

LaTeXTools provides a "basic" builder, which takes care of running `pdflatex`, then `bibtex` or `biber` as necessary followed by `pdflatex` twice.

After installing LaTeXTools, navigate to the user settings.

[image: image showing navigating to Preferences > Package Settings > LaTeXTools > Settings - User]

Then scroll down to the `builder` setting and change its value to `basic`

[image: image showing changing "builder" setting to "basic"]

#### Using "script" build:

After installing LaTeXTools, navigate to the user settings.

[image]

Then alter the builder settings to `script`

[image]

and you can use a script. In the below example, for Windows, the build would run `pdflatex` then `biber` then `pdflatex` twice on the file.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

## Inlage

---

**Adding `biber` as a new menu in `PDFLaTeX & biber`**

Go to `Build` → `Compiler Options`:

[image]

This opens:

[image]

Now,

1. Choose `PDFLaTeX & BibTeX`
2. Press `Duplicate` to get a copy of `PDFLaTeX & BibTeX`.
3. Now press `Rename` and rename `PDFLaTeX & BibTeX copy` to `PDFLaTeX & Biber` as shown below:

[image]

Now you should have a profile named `PDFLaTeX & Biber`. Open it. Select `BibTeX` (arrow 2). Choose `Binary Name` (arrow 3) as in this figure:

[image]

Save and you will have `PDFLaTeX & Biber` build menu as:

[image]

Which will execute `pdflatex` → `biber` → `pdflatex` → `pdflatex`.

---

**`Biber` as standalone**

Go to `Build` → `Compiler Options`  as explained above.

Now,

1. Choose `PDFLaTeX`
2. Press `Duplicate` to get a copy of `PDFLaTeX`.
3. Now press `Rename` and rename `PDFLaTeX copy` to `Biber` as explained eariler.
4. Make changes in `Binary Name` as shown below:

[image]

After saving, you will get a build menu named `Biber`:

[image]

This will run *only* biber.

Answer (score 5):

Editor name: SublimeText / Sublime LaTeX package.
https://tekonomist.wordpress.com

main.tex first line should say

```
%!TEX program = <program> 
%\ program: one of pdflatex (the default), xelatex or lualatex. This 
%\ selects the TeX engine.
```

bibliography.bib first 2 lines should say

```
%!TEX program = bibtex
%!TEX root = main.tex
```

Comment: instructions are from [SublimeText/LaTeXTools on GitHub](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) section: **"Build engine settings"**

Comment: Are you sure the first line of `bibliography.bib` should be `bibtex` instead of `biber`?

Comment: Is there a way to have Biber as the bibliography compiler on a global scale in Sublime or is it always necessary to specify the use of Biber on a per-document basis?

Comment: Speaking as a developer of LaTeXTools, I can assure you this doesn't work or if it does it is only by accident.

Answer (score 5):

## (vanilla) Emacs (*i.e.*, Emacs without AUCTeX)

---

[**tl;dr**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR): `(setq tex-bibtex-command "biber")` and then (i) <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd>, (ii) <kbd>C-c TAB</kbd>, and (iii) <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd>

---

If, for whatever reason, you're stuck using Emacs without AUCTeX,<sup>1</sup> you can configure the TeX print commands of [TeX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/TeX-Mode.html) to use Biber instead of BibTeX.

There are several print commands to be aware of:

- <kbd>C-c C-b</kbd>: Invoke TeX on the entire current buffer (`tex-buffer`)
- <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd>: Invoke TeX on the current file (`tex-file`)
- <kbd>C-c TAB</kbd>: Invoke BibTeX on the current file (`tex-bibtex-file`)

<kbd>C-c C-b</kbd> is useful if you want to test something out, but it creates temporary files with different names, so it is not really useful for sorting out bibliographies and crossreferencing, which depend on auxiliary files.

To get bibliography and crossreference stuff right, use <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd>. This command will first ask if want to save your buffer (if you have a modified buffer); then, it runs either `tex-run-command` or `latex-run-command`, depending on whether you are currently in `plain-tex-mode` or `latex-mode` (see the [TeX mode page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/TeX-Mode.html) for a description of how the mode is chosen.)

By default, `tex-run-command` is set to `tex` and `latex-run-command` is set to `latex`. If you'd like to use the PDF versions, you can add the following to your Emacs configuration:

```
(setq tex-run-command "pdftex")
(setq latex-run-command "pdflatex")
```

Next, you can use <kbd>C-c TAB</kbd> to invoke either BibTeX or Biber. <kbd>C-c TAB</kbd> runs `tex-bibtex-command`, which is, by default, `bibtex`.

Like with the `*tex-run-command`s, you can change this to `biber` by adding the following configuration:

```
(setq tex-bibtex-command "biber")
```

After you've made these changes, you can then go through the LaTeX -> Biber -> LaTex compilation steps with <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd> -> <kbd>C-c TAB</kbd> -> <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd>.

---

1. But really, you should probably use Emacs with AUCTeX, in which case see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154753/32888).

Answer (score 3):

## LaTeXila/GNOME LaTeX

### `latexmk` is the default build tool

By default GNOME LaTeX (formerly LaTeXila) uses [`latexmk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) as a build tool. `latexmk` can automatically figure out if and when to run Biber, so there is no pressing need to actually set up that editor for Biber. The standard build settings will do just fine.

### Biber only

In case you do want to set up a build job to only run Biber, follow these steps.

1. Select *Manage Build Tools* in the *Build* menu

   [image: Build>Manage Build Tools]
2. In the *Manage Build Tools* window select the little plus to the bottom of the right *Personal Build Tools* column

   [image: Personal Build Tools menu]
3. Fill out the fields as follows

   - *Label:* `Biber` (this is the name shown in the menu later, of course you may pick anything else, but 'Biber' seems sensible)
   - *Description:* `run Biber` (again, the value of this field is not important for Biber to actually work)
   - Add a new job to the *Jobs* list by clicking the plus button on the bottom
   - *Commands:* `biber $shortname`, *Post Processor:* `all-output`

   Things should look roughly like

   [image: Personal Build Tool window filled out as described above]

Now you can select Biber from the second (custom) group of the *Build* menu whenever you want to run it manually.

[image: Build menu with Biber available]

Answer (score 0):

## Eclipse Texlipse program

Latex can be used in eclise
http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/

Install the texlipse extension
Click on external tool configuration
[image: external tool configuration]
[image]
Click on program new configuration
[image]
Point to your program path
[image]
Do the same for biber
[image]
If you are using statet to get from Rnw => Tex => output
you can configure the program using R code. You
[image]